# How to convert Python Pandas Dataframe to R data.frame

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I'm using the R package `PythonInR`, and wanted to convert the pandas dataframe to R dataframe using function `pyGet()`, but I got the error below:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(xi, optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class ""PythonObject"" to a data.frame

The text.csv file only contains two columns, name(string) and value(int).
The code is as below:

```
library(PythonInR) 
pyConnect() 
pyIsConnected() 
pyVersion()
pyOptions("usePandas", TRUE) 
pyImport("pandas", as="pd") 
test_code <-'py_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")' 
pyExec(code = test_code) 
r_df <- pyGet("py_df")
```

And the output of the code is:

```
library(PythonInR)
pyConnect()
R is already connected to Python!
pyIsConnected()
[1] TRUE
pyVersion()
[1] "3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]"
pyOptions("usePandas", TRUE)
pyImport("pandas", as="pd")
test_code <- 'py_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")'
pyExec(code = test_code)
r_df <- pyGet("py_df")
```

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
>         cannot coerce class ""PythonObject"" to a data.frame

Can anyone help to suggest how to convert a Pandas data frame to R data.frame using `PythonInR`?

Comment: Why not just use R's `read.table` rather than pursuing such a round about method?  Or just stay in Python. There doesn't seem to be any case for synergy here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I just need to combine R and Python codes in one of the projects as one whole data processing flow, which will require the conversion between Python and R objects

Comment: Have you heard of the [feather project](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/)?

Comment: Thanks Roman for your suggestion, yes feather can be used for both Python and R, but how can I transfer the feather object created in R to my Python code, other than write it as local file and then read into Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use json. The pandas dataframe has a `to_json` method and you can use the `rjson` R package to read the json string using `fromJSON`.

You may also find [this](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/pysockr) and [this](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/pynterface) interesting. Planning to submit to CRAN soon, but I need to do more testing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! From my understanding, I still need to write the json file to local and then read it into R. But I wonder is there a way to convert between R and Python objects that does not require reading and writing? cuz I can already call Python code from R.

Comment: @yichi-liu, it depends on your workflow but you can `pyExec` the json module import and write the `to_JSON` output to a Python string variable, and transfer that to R with `pyGet`.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say why it is not working.

Do you have a reproducible example, or can you provide "test.csv".
If you think it's a bug, you could write the package author a mail.

As far I see,

```
sessionInfo()

## R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
## 
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS: /home/florian/bin/R_dev/lib/libRblas.so
## LAPACK: /home/florian/bin/R_dev/lib/libRlapack.so
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=de_AT.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_AT.UTF-8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=de_AT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_AT.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=de_AT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] knitr_1.16      PythonInR_0.1-3
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] compiler_3.4.0 magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.1       markdown_0.8  
## [5] tools_3.4.0    stringi_1.1.5  pack_0.1-1     stringr_1.2.0 
## [9] evaluate_0.10
```

_

```
library(PythonInR)
pyConnect() 
## R is already connected to Python!
```

_

```
pyIsConnected() 
## [1] TRUE
```

_

```
pyVersion()
## [1] "2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:01:26) \n[GCC 4.9.2]"
```

_

```
pyOptions("usePandas", TRUE) 
pyImport("pandas", as="pd")
```

_

```
pySet("x", head(cars))   
pyExecp("x")
##    dist  speed
## 0     2      4
## 1    10      4
## 2     4      7
## 3    22      7
## 4    16      8
## 5    10      9
```

_

```
pyExecp("type(x)")
## <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
str(pyGet("x"))
## 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ speed: num  4 4 7 7 8 9
##  $ dist : num  2 10 4 22 16 10
```

Comment: It looks like OP opened a bug report on PythonInR [Cannot convert Python Pandas Dataframe to R](https://bitbucket.org/Floooo/pythoninr/issues/16/cannot-convert-python-pandas-dataframe-to).  Based on his example I would guess that it's having trouble converting the `name` column which contains strings.  Strings are not a native `pandas` data type so it falls back to using a "Python Object" to store those. I barely know `pandas` and don't have `R`, but you could test this by rerunning your code using a csv that contains a column of string values.